# How do I create a new column in pandas based on an or statement for multiple existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to clean a data set. I have a table that looks like this:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I want to add a column (ColE) to the dataframe with a value of 1 if any of the 4 columns has a value of 1. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that often it's a good idea to store boolean/binary data as `bool` dtype instead of integer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.any`:

```
df['ColE'] = df.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE
0     1     0     1     0     1
1     0     0     1     0     1
2     1     1     0     0     1
3     1     0     1     1     1
```

And you can filter columns to check like this:

```
cols = ['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD']
df['ColE'] = df[cols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```